# urllib.request.urlopen returns nothing to a list and throws an indexerror

Tags: python, urllib

```
query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : "example"()})
html_content_request = urllib.request.Request(
    "http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string,
    headers=headers
)
html_content_open = urllib.request.urlopen(html_content_request)
search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content_open.read().decode())
videoURL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0]
```

I am trying to get an youtube video's link based on this search "example" for example, this should return the url of the first video of that search.
The original code:

```
query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({"search_query" : "example"()})
html_content = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string)
search_results = re.findall(r'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
print("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0])
```

works on some websites, but on YouTube, it gives a 403  error, thats why I have that modified code up there.
My code, the first one throws an IndexError, traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Sakari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in 
__call__
return self.func(*args)
File "c:/Users/Sakari/Desktop/Python projektit/pyGTARADIO.py", line 96, in <lambda>
lataus_button = tk.Button(radioFrame, text = "Lataa musiikkikansioon", command = lambda: ytLataus())
File "c:/Users/Sakari/Desktop/Python projektit/pyGTARADIO.py", line 51, in ytLataus
ytSearch()
File "c:/Users/Sakari/Desktop/Python projektit/pyGTARADIO.py", line 44, in ytSearch
videoURL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: first check what you have in `search_results` - it seems you have empty list so you can't get `[0]` from empty list.

Comment: search_results can be empty, you need to add a check if its not empty. you can add somthing like `if search_results:`

Comment: second: you should check `html_content` - maybe it sends you different HTML then you expect. Maybe links doesn't fit to you regex. OR there is no links. Maybe page uses JavaScript to add links to HTML but urllib can't run JavaScript.

Comment: furas, sorry but can you clarify, as I dont quite get what you said about regex? Thanks

Comment: I didn't check links on page but I want say that links may not fit to `'href=\"\/watch\?v=(.{11})'` - ie. they can have less then 11 chars (`.{11}`) or they can use prefix `"https://` , etc.

Comment: I run your code and it fives me link. The only idea that server blocks your script and it send page with warning or recaptcha. You should first check what you get in `html_content`. You can `print()` it or save it in file and open in web browser.

Comment: Okay, how can I avoid being blocked?